# Android: Low profile mode with a keyboard

Tags: android

I have an app that uses `LOW_PROFILE_MODE` to hide soft buttons.
It works quite ok, but when I select a `TextView` and the software keyboard appears on the screen, the `LOW_PROFILE_MODE` is gone.

Is there a way to use android soft keyboard and stay in `LOW_PROFILE_MODE` on `Android 5+`?

Comment: My primary goals is to disallow users to click software overview button.

Comment: But using low profile mode (or any other mode) does not prevent the user from accessing the soft key bar. It just makes it less visible or requires an extra action to access it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: I have done some hacks and a user is not able to access soft key bar until keyboard is shown.

Comment: Sounds shady. I hope you're not trying to get this into Google Play.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: No, I am not.

Comment: In that case couldn't you just use full screen mode and screen pinning? Screen pinning makes it actually not possible to get out of your application.